# Execute loop only once if condition is met

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a pythonic way to write a code equivalent to the one below without defining `doSomething` as a separate function.

```py
if test:
    for i in s:
        doSomething()
else:
    doSomething()
```

In particular, I am thinking of the use case where `test` checks if `s` exists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I did not downvote, but it might help to clarify the use case.

Comment: I like your code better than either of the two answers. It is much easier to understand what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: Better now, @iota?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to execute `dosomething` once if `s` exists, otherwise `len(s)` times.

```
for i in s if test else [0]:
    dosomething()
```

The iteratable is a ternary expression:

```
s if test else [0]
```

The `else` value can be any sequence of a single element; since you don't actually use the `i` value for `dosomething`, it could also be more clear:

```
limit = len(s) if test else 1
for i in range(limit):
    dosomething()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could possibly do this:

```py
for i in (s if test else [False]):
    doSomething()
```